# Make a selection in 2 tables with only one SQL request

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

i want a good intel about how to do such a thing :
select everything from my table 1 and my table 2 where the id_article of my table 2 is equal to id from my table 1...I try this :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS n, table2 AS a WHERE n.id = a.id_article
```

But it didn't work...I don't understand the whole process though....

Thanks for any clue

Comment: [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables).

Comment: your query is absolutely fine although you are using the old syntax of join. how come it is not working?

Comment: maybe my way to catch results is not good because i have no error. i see that. But thanks for the tips :)

Comment: The problem is probably in your PHP, since the SQL is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) statement.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 
  JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.id_article
```

Optionally you can add `WHERE` conditions in the end

Comment: Yes, thanks with this syntax, i was obviously some years late ^^

Comment: If this works then so should your original. They're two different ways of writing the same query, yours is just an older syntax.

Comment: Yes but i don't have any results...No error though...i'm looking for my way to catch results, it is obviously wrong

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use the new syntax format of the query, `ANSI SQL-92`.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.ID = b.ID_Article
```

To fully understand about joins, see the article below

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Disregarding the fact that the join syntax is preferable, I don't see what's wrong with his query, do you?  Just wondering if this will work any better if his didn't work to begin with, or maybe there is a mistake in his query that I just don't see...

Comment: @BrandonMoore as stated in my comment above, the query is fine. maybe the OP want *OUTER JOINs*, not sure. But the question is too incomplete.

Comment: Cool, didn't see your comment up there and was just wondering if I was missing something obvious :)

Comment: Well i don't have any results, maybe my calls are not good because i have no error messages.

Comment: the best way you do is to add sample records and desired result along your question `:D`

Comment: here my syntax :
$req00=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles JOIN images ON articles.id = images.id_article");

     while ($res00=mysql_fetch_array($req00)){     
 echo $res00['chemin'];
}

Nothing happens with my echo...Where 'chemin' is a row of my images table

Comment: are you certainly sure that there are `ID` on table `articles` that matches on `ID_Articles` on table `images`?

Comment: execute the query in phpmyadmin and see if the query works first. then we can fix php problems after :)

Comment: lol, yes it is, i have no registred item in my second table ^^. The whole thing works better with something in it :) Thanks to everyone !